# Prevent an ArrayController from adding a model which failed validation

Tags: javascript, ember.js

The workflow is:

1. User is on the New Page.
2. Hits save, causing model validations to fail. Errors bound to the model are shown. Still on the same page.
3. The user now navigates to the Index page and sees the invalid record added to the list.

The ArrayController seems to be adding records which failed validations.

```
App.CompaniesNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    model: function(){
      var company = App.Company.createRecord();
      this.wireObservers(company, this);
      return company;
    },

    events: {
      save: function(){
        var controller = this.controllerFor(this.routeName);
        controller.get('transaction').commit();
      }
    },

   wireObservers: function(company, router) {
     company.on('becameInvalid', function(record){
      // do something to remove it from the arraycontroller
      // record.rollback();
     });

     company.on('didCreate', function(){
       router.transitionTo('companies.index')
     });
   })
})
```

The `becameInvalid` event does get called. Doing a `record.rollback()` throws an exception:

```
Uncaught Error: Attempted to handle event `becameClean` on     <App.Company:ember612:null> while in state rootState.loaded.created.invalid. Called with undefined ember-data.js:3495
DS.StateManager.Ember.StateManager.extend.unhandledEvent ember-data.js:3495
```

Is there a way to prevent ArrayController to add records which failed validation.

Answer (score 1):

Try to rollback the transaction through the store instead.

```
   wireObservers: function(company, router) {
     var _self = this;
     company.on('becameInvalid', function(record){
      // do something to remove it from the arraycontroller
       _self.store.rollback();
     });

     company.on('didCreate', function(){
       router.transitionTo('companies.index')
     });
   })
```

You should consider creating a specific transaction for the purpose rather than using the default one. To create a new transaction inside a route,  you can do the following

```
App.MyRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    transaction: this.store.transaction();
})
```

and then create your record and add it to the transaction using

```
var company = this.transaction.createRecord(App.Company);
```

and finally commit or rollback the transaction

```
this.transaction.commit();
this.transaction.rollback();
```

Comment: This seems like a nice pattern, and I'm using it now. However the problem still remains, i.e. The ArrayController adds the object rollback'ed and hence is shown on the Index page. However now `rollback` doesn't throw any exceptions.

Comment: Can you setup  a jsbin or jsfiddle with your code, seems to me that the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks. For now I've solved this using a completely different pattern. Will let you know if I see this problem again.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I think a rollback() is not the solution, because the transaction has already been committed ; even if the server validation fails, the record has been added to the ArrayController content.

The solution I could see would be to use the deleteRecord function, with something like this :

```
wireObservers: function(company, router) {
 company.on('becameInvalid', function(record){
   record.deleteRecord();
 });

 company.on('didCreate', function(){
   router.transitionTo('companies.index');
 });
```

})

I've just a question about your workflow. When you get an validation error, and leave the page, it means the user cancelled the record creation