# Ember Data and dirty records

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

What is the recommended way of discarding changes made to records?

I have the following logic to revert dirty records to their original state.

```
if controller.get('isDirty')
  controller.get('content').rollback()
```

This works **unless** an unsuccessful attempt has been made to commit the record.

If I try to commit the changes and the server responds with errors, it's no longer possible to rollback the record this way. In this case, does Ember Data or the RESTAdapter provide a built-in method of reverting the record to its original state?

---

I'm using the packaged `DS.RESTAdapter` with Ember Data revision 11

Comment: I have the same problem is. Does this happen because of a problem in Ember-data?

Answer (score 2):

I've found something that apparently works although I don't know why. Here is what I do in my model:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({

  becameInvalid: function(errors) {
    this.get('transaction').rollback();
    //this.rollback(); <- This doesn't work. You get becameClean error.
  }
});
```

The comment from [sly7-7](https://github.com/sly7-7) for that [issue](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/640) gave me the idea.

Comment: Cheers man. This helped me out, added it to a controllers action. ala embers todo list:

`acceptChanges: function(){ this.set('is_editing', false); if (Ember.isEmpty(this.get("model.title"))){this.get('model').rollback();} else {this.get('model').save();}},`

Answer (score 1):

create/update your record through a transaction in a router. See more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633564/prevent-an-arraycontroller-from-adding-a-model-which-failed-validation/14638492#14638492) on how to do that.

```
var transaction = App.store.transaction()
transaction.createRecord(App.Foo);
transaction.commit()
transaction.rollback()
```